# how to change the width of multiple div countainer columns on hover at the same time

Tags: html, css

I made four vertical side-by-side columns with div containers
when a specific column is hovered over I want that column width to increase to 70% and the remaining columns to decrease to 10% floating in there line order

for example when column_about is hovered over it will float to the right and increase to 70% while the remaining columns float to the left and decrease to 10% staying in the vertical line.
and when the next column column_skills is hovered over it will increase to 70% and float retaliative to where it is positioned while column_about decreases to 10% and floats to the right and columns _ref _port decrease and float left 
and so-on and so-forth

once the column has been increased in width i want to be able to have context appear like images, tables, text, but I do not want the context to look squished when the column in not enlarged.

I am a beginner so i apologize for any confusing lingo thx :)

```css
    .column_about
{
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 width: 40%;
 height: 700px;
 float: right;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.column_about:hover
{
 width: 70%;
 height: 700px;
}

.column_skills
{
 background-color: #434343;
 width: 20%;
 height: 700px;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.column_skills:hover
{
 width: 70%;
 height: 700px;
 
}

.column_ref
{
 background-color: #FAEBCD;
 width: 20%;
 height: 700px;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.column_ref:hover
{
 width: 70%;
 height: 700px;
}

.column_port
{
 background-color: #F7C873;
 width: 20%;
 height: 700px;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.column_port:hover
{
 width: 70%;
 height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="column_about">
  <p>
  about me
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="column_skills">
  <p>
  skills/experence
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="column_ref">
  <p>
  references
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="column_port">
  <p>
  portfolio
  </p>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a `.column-container` that everything is inside, so the columns will be set even, until you hover over a column. There's also a `.column` class in each column, so the column style wouldn't have to be repeated.

```css
.column {
    width: 25%;
    height: 700px;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column_about { background-color: #F8F8F8; }

.column_skills { background-color: #434343; }

.column_ref { background-color: #FAEBCD; }

.column_port { background-color: #F7C873; }

body:hover .column:not(:hover) {
    width: 10%;
}

.column:hover {
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
 <div class="column column_about">
  <p>about me</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column column_skills">
  <p>skills/experence</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column column_ref">
        <p>references</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column column_port">
  <p>portfolio</p>
 </div>
</div>
```